# uWSGI - a Django view function send out https requests to other server and fail to get response via uWSGI

Tags: django-views, uwsgi

I have tried many times to solve this issue but no solution till now. The system frame is CentOS 6.5 + Django + nWSGI + Nginx. My views function in Django needs to send out an https request to other server. I run up the Django app by uWSGI and it broke up when a visit comes, even after I try to capture the exception in the view. But if I run up Django app directly by python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8050, the problem disapper. Or when app send http instead of https request, the problem doesn't show up yet.

## uWSGI error

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 27816)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 27820, cores: 4)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 27821, cores: 4)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 27822, cores: 4)
enter process request, current url: /api/auth/
reg, match result: /login/ None
reg, match result: /api/verifycode/ None
reg, match result: /api/.* <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='/api/auth/'>
-s [-s] -s
enter process request, current url: /api/auth/
reg, match result: /login/ None
reg, match result: /api/verifycode/ None
reg, match result: /api/.* <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='/api/auth/'>
*** glibc detected *** /opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000009d2340 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x33bb075f4e]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x33bb078cad]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(CRYPTO_free+0x1d)[0x302e66ae2d]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(ASN1_STRING_free+0x2d)[0x302e713efd]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(ASN1_primitive_free+0x7d)[0x302e70889d]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(ASN1_primitive_free+0xdb)[0x302e7088fb]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(ASN1_template_free+0x8f)[0x302e708c7f]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10[0x302e708b66]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(ASN1_template_free+0x8f)[0x302e708c7f]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10[0x302e708b66]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10(ASN1_item_free+0x15)[0x302e708cb5]
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10(ssl_cert_free+0x7f)[0x302ee4694f]
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10(SSL_free+0x11e)[0x302ee455de]
/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x12302)[0x7f282906b302]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x505a45]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyObjectDict_SetItem+0xa6)[0x5082f6]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(PyObject_GenericSetAttr+0x116)[0x5175d6]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(PyObject_SetAttr+0x5a)[0x51685a]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0xe8b)[0x5813eb]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x4ddd54]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x4ddd54]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x4ddd54]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7f85)[0x5884e5]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x4ddd54]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x4ddd54]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x4ddd54]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x4ddd54]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d97)[0x5862f7]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x64a517]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x605b)[0x5865bb]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(PyVectorcall_Call+0x61)[0x4dc831]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3a40)[0x583fa0]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7f85)[0x5884e5]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x64a517]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(PyVectorcall_Call+0x61)[0x4dc831]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3a40)[0x583fa0]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi[0x64a517]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(PyVectorcall_Call+0x61)[0x4dc831]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3a40)[0x583fa0]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x79c)[0x57fe9c]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0xce)[0x4db83e]
/opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi(PyVectorcall_Call+0x61)[0x4dc831]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-007ae000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1185049                            /opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi
009ae000-009f8000 rw-p 003ae000 fc:01 1185049                            /opt/env_zhixing/bin/uwsgi
009f8000-00a1f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01bf7000-02652000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02652000-027e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
302de00000-302de16000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262188                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
302de16000-302e015000 ---p 00016000 fc:01 262188                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
302e015000-302e016000 rw-p 00015000 fc:01 262188                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
302e600000-302e7ba000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1079407                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
302e7ba000-302e9ba000 ---p 001ba000 fc:01 1079407                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
302e9ba000-302e9d5000 r--p 001ba000 fc:01 1079407                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
302e9d5000-302e9e1000 rw-p 001d5000 fc:01 1079407                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
302e9e1000-302e9e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
302ea00000-302ea20000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1079431                        /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0.0.0
302ea20000-302ec20000 ---p 00020000 fc:01 1079431                        /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0.0.0
302ec20000-302ec21000 rw-p 00020000 fc:01 1079431                        /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.0.0.0
302ee00000-302ee62000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1056851                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
302ee62000-302f062000 ---p 00062000 fc:01 1056851                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
302f062000-302f066000 r--p 00062000 fc:01 1056851                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
302f066000-302f06c000 rw-p 00066000 fc:01 1056851                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
33ba800000-33ba820000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262151                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
33baa1f000-33baa20000 r--p 0001f000 fc:01 262151                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
33baa20000-33baa21000 rw-p 00020000 fc:01 262151                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
33baa21000-33baa22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
33bac00000-33bac15000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262271                         /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
33bac15000-33bae14000 ---p 00015000 fc:01 262271                         /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
33bae14000-33bae15000 r--p 00014000 fc:01 262271                         /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
33bae15000-33bae16000 rw-p 00015000 fc:01 262271                         /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
33bb000000-33bb18a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262157                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33bb18a000-33bb38a000 ---p 0018a000 fc:01 262157                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33bb38a000-33bb38e000 r--p 0018a000 fc:01 262157                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33bb38e000-33bb38f000 rw-p 0018e000 fc:01 262157                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33bb38f000-33bb394000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
33bb400000-33bb417000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262166                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
33bb417000-33bb617000 ---p 00017000 fc:01 262166                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
33bb617000-33bb618000 r--p 00017000 fc:01 262166                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
33bb618000-33bb619000 rw-p 00018000 fc:01 262166                         /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
33bb619000-33bb61d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
33bb800000-33bb802000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262171                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
33bb802000-33bba02000 ---p 00002000 fc:01 262171                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
33bba02000-33bba03000 r--p 00002000 fc:01 262171                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
33bba03000-33bba04000 rw-p 00003000 fc:01 262171                         /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
33bbc00000-33bbc07000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262189                         /lib64/librt-2.12.so
33bbc07000-33bbe06000 ---p 00007000 fc:01 262189                         /lib64/librt-2.12.so
33bbe06000-33bbe07000 r--p 00006000 fc:01 262189                         /lib64/librt-2.12.so
33bbe07000-33bbe08000 rw-p 00007000 fc:01 262189                         /lib64/librt-2.12.so
33bc000000-33bc083000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262273                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
33bc083000-33bc282000 ---p 00083000 fc:01 262273                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
33bc282000-33bc283000 r--p 00082000 fc:01 262273                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
33bc283000-33bc284000 rw-p 00083000 fc:01 262273                         /lib64/libm-2.12.so
33bcc00000-33bcc02000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262197                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
33bcc02000-33bce01000 ---p 00002000 fc:01 262197                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
33bce01000-33bce02000 r--p 00001000 fc:01 262197                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
33bce02000-33bce03000 rw-p 00002000 fc:01 262197                         /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
33bd000000-33bd016000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 270875                         /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
33bd016000-33bd216000 ---p 00016000 fc:01 270875                         /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
33bd216000-33bd217000 r--p 00016000 fc:01 270875                         /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
33bd217000-33bd218000 rw-p 00017000 fc:01 270875                         /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
33bd218000-33bd21a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
33bdc00000-33bdc71000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262173                         /lib64/libfreebl3.so
33bdc71000-33bde70000 ---p 00071000 fc:01 262173                         /lib64/libfreebl3.so
33bde70000-33bde72000 r--p 00070000 fc:01 262173                         /lib64/libfreebl3.so
33bde72000-33bde73000 rw-p 00072000 fc:01 262173                         /lib64/libfreebl3.so
33bde73000-33bde77000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
33be400000-33be402000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1059775                        /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
33be402000-33be602000 ---p 00002000 fc:01 1059775                        /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
33be602000-33be603000 rw-p 00002000 fc:01 1059775                        /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
33bec00000-33bec07000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262181                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
33bec07000-33bee07000 ---p 00007000 fc:01 262181                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
33bee07000-33bee08000 r--p 00007000 fc:01 262181                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
33bee08000-33bee09000 rw-p 00008000 fc:01 262181                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
33bee09000-33bee37000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
33c0000000-33c0010000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 270870                         /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.4
33c0010000-33c020f000 ---p 00010000 fc:01 270870                         /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.4
33c020f000-33c0211000 rw-p 0000f000 fc:01 270870                         /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.4
362ae00000-362ae1d000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 262269                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
362ae1d000-362b01c000 ---p 0001d000 fc:01 262269                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
362b01c000-362b01d000 r--p 0001c000 fc:01 262269                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
362b01d000-362b01e000 rw-p 0001d000 fc:01 262269                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
362b01e000-362b01f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
362b200000-362b23f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1065050                        /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
362b23f000-362b43f000 ---p 0003f000 fc:01 1065050                        /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
362b43f000-362b440000 rw-p 0003f000 fc:01 1065050                        /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
362b440000-362b450000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
362c600000-362c603000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 269346                         /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
362c603000-362c802000 ---p 00003000 fc:01 269346                         /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
362c802000-362c803000 r--p 00002000 fc:01 269346                         /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
362c803000-362c804000 rw-p 00003000 fc:01 269346                         /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
362ce00000-362ce41000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 269348                         /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
362ce41000-362d041000 ---p 00041000 fc:01 269348                         /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
362d041000-362d042000 r--p 00041000 fc:01 269348                         /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
362d042000-362d044000 rw-p 00042000 fc:01 269348                         /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
362d200000-362d20a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 269344                         /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
362d20a000-362d409000 ---p 0000a000 fc:01 269344                         /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
362d409000-362d40a000 r--p 00009000 fc:01 269344                         /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
362d40a000-362d40b000 rw-p 0000a000 fc:01 269344                         /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
362da00000-362dadb000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 269347                         /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
362dadb000-362dcdb000 ---p 000db000 fc:01 269347                         /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
362dcdb000-362dce5000 r--p 000db000 fc:01 269347                         /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
362dce5000-362dce7000 rw-p 000e5000 fc:01 269347                         /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
362de00000-362de02000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 265467                         /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
362de02000-362e001000 ---p 00002000 fc:01 265467                         /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
362e001000-362e002000 r--p 00001000 fc:01 265467                         /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
362e002000-362e003000 rw-p 00002000 fc:01 265467                         /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
362e600000-362e629000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 269345                         /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
362e629000-362e829000 ---p 00029000 fc:01 269345                         /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
362e829000-362e82a000 r--p 00029000 fc:01 269345                         /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
362e82a000-362e82b000 rw-p 0002a000 fc:01 269345                         /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
362e82b000-362e82c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
362ea00000-362eb49000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1071754                        /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6
362eb49000-362ed48000 ---p 00149000 fc:01 1071754                        /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6
362ed48000-362ed52000 rw-p 00148000 fc:01 1071754                        /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6
362ed52000-362ed53000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
362fa00000-362fa1e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1051938                        /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
362fa1e000-362fc1e000 ---p 0001e000 fc:01 1051938                        /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
362fc1e000-362fc1f000 rw-p 0001e000 fc:01 1051938                        /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f2814000000-7f2814021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2814021000-7f2818000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2818000000-7f2818021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2818021000-7f281c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f281c000000-7f281c100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f281c100000-7f2820000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f282373d000-7f282377e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f282377e000-7f28237ba000 r--s 00000000 fc:01 786460                     /var/db/nscd/hosts
7f28237ba000-7f2823cfa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2823cfa000-7f2823cfb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2823cfb000-7f28246fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28246fb000-7f28246fc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28246fc000-7f28250fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28250fc000-7f28250fd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28250fd000-7f2825afd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2825afd000-7f2825b3d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2825b3d000-7f2825ba3000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 2100842                    /opt/env_zhixing/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2825ba3000-7f2825da3000 ---p 00066000 fc:01 2100842                    /opt/env_zhixing/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2825da3000-7f2825daa000 rw-p 00066000 fc:01 2100842                    /opt/env_zhixing/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2825daa000-7f282612a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f282612a000-7f2826132000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843442                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2826132000-7f2826331000 ---p 00008000 fc:01 1843442                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2826331000-7f2826333000 rw-p 00007000 fc:01 1843442                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2826333000-7f28265f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28265f3000-7f28265f5000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1192808                    /opt/env_zhixing/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markupsafe/_speedups.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28265f5000-7f28267f5000 ---p 00002000 fc:01 1192808                    /opt/env_zhixing/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markupsafe/_speedups.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28267f5000-7f28267f6000 rw-p 00002000 fc:01 1192808                    /opt/env_zhixing/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markupsafe/_speedups.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28267f6000-7f2826ef7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2826ef7000-7f2826efb000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1847010                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2826efb000-7f28270fa000 ---p 00004000 fc:01 1847010                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28270fa000-7f28270fb000 rw-p 00003000 fc:01 1847010                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28270fb000-7f2827117000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843379                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827117000-7f2827317000 ---p 0001c000 fc:01 1843379                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827317000-7f2827319000 rw-p 0001c000 fc:01 1843379                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827319000-7f28275d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28275d9000-7f28276e1000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843411                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28276e1000-7f28278e1000 ---p 00108000 fc:01 1843411                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28278e1000-7f28278e3000 rw-p 00108000 fc:01 1843411                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f28278e3000-7f2827923000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2827923000-7f2827935000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1847018                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827935000-7f2827b34000 ---p 00012000 fc:01 1847018                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827b34000-7f2827b36000 rw-p 00011000 fc:01 1847018                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827b36000-7f2827b40000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1847025                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827b40000-7f2827d40000 ---p 0000a000 fc:01 1847025                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827d40000-7f2827d41000 rw-p 0000a000 fc:01 1847025                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827d41000-7f2827d47000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1847007                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827d47000-7f2827f46000 ---p 00006000 fc:01 1847007                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827f46000-7f2827f47000 rw-p 00005000 fc:01 1847007                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827f47000-7f2827f87000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2827f87000-7f2827f8c000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843399                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2827f8c000-7f282818b000 ---p 00005000 fc:01 1843399                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282818b000-7f282818d000 rw-p 00004000 fc:01 1843399                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282818d000-7f28281cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28281cd000-7f282821f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1846999                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282821f000-7f282841f000 ---p 00052000 fc:01 1846999                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282841f000-7f2828422000 rw-p 00052000 fc:01 1846999                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2828422000-7f2828522000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2828522000-7f282852f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843413                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_asyncio.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282852f000-7f282872e000 ---p 0000d000 fc:01 1843413                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_asyncio.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282872e000-7f2828731000 rw-p 0000c000 fc:01 1843413                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_asyncio.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2828731000-7f2828732000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843398                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_contextvars.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2828732000-7f2828931000 ---p 00001000 fc:01 1843398                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_contextvars.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2828931000-7f2828932000 rw-p 00000000 fc:01 1843398                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_contextvars.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2828932000-7f28289b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f28289b2000-7f2828bbf000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1190529                    /root/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f2828bbf000-7f2828dbf000 ---p 0020d000 fc:01 1190529                    /root/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f2828dbf000-7f2828de6000 rw-p 0020d000 fc:01 1190529                    /root/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f2828de6000-7f2828dea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2828dea000-7f2828e4f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1190530                    /root/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f2828e4f000-7f282904f000 ---p 00065000 fc:01 1190530                    /root/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f282904f000-7f2829059000 rw-p 00065000 fc:01 1190530                    /root/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f2829059000-7f282907e000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1847004                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282907e000-7f282927d000 ---p 00025000 fc:01 1847004                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282927d000-7f2829284000 rw-p 00024000 fc:01 1847004                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2829284000-7f2829304000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2829304000-7f282930d000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843407                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282930d000-7f282950d000 ---p 00009000 fc:01 1843407                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282950d000-7f282950e000 rw-p 00009000 fc:01 1843407                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f282950e000-7f282988e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f282988e000-7f2829895000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 1843397                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2829895000-7f2829a95000 ---p 00007000 fc:01 1843397                    /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f2829a95000-7f2829a96000 rw-p 00007000 fc:01 1843397                    

7f2832e07000-7f2832e08000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff199a2000-7fff199c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff199f4000-7fff199f5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
DAMN ! worker 3 (pid: 27822) died, killed by signal 6 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 3 (new pid: 27836)
```

## Django Views.py

version 3.2

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests

# Create your views here.

def auth(request,*args,**kwargs):
    try:

        response = requests.get("https://www.baidu.com")
        print("status_code",response.status_code)
        return HttpResponse("hello world")
    except:
        return HttpResponse("system broken up")
```

## uWSGI.ini

version 2.0.20

```
[uwsgi]
http =  0.0.0.0:8050 
chdir           = /opt/env_zhixing/zhixingyi
module          = zhixingyi.wsgi
home            = /opt/env_zhixing
master          = true
processes       = 3
vacuum          = true
```

## CentOs

CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

## Instance

Aliyun ECS

By debugging, I found uWSGI is the problem.  I have upgrade or downgrade uWSGI, re-installed uWSGI and python3.8 and all support softwares. No use at all. Even switch requests to urllib, same error.
The engineer Aliyun suggest me change the OS from CentOS 6.5 to 7. But that will cost much time and so complicated.

Is there someone facing the similar problem and know how to fix it ?  Thanks much.